# Prove that set is perfect

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $E$ be the set of all $x\in [0,1]$ whose decimal expansion contains only the digits $4$ and $7$. Is $E$ perfect?

**Proof:** [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1357247/126389) was proved that $E$ is closed set in $[0,1]$ (also in $\mathbb{R}^1$). We'll prove that any point $x\in E$ is a limit point of $E$. It means if $x\in E$ then $\forall \varepsilon>0$ deleted neighborhood of $x$ $N'_{\varepsilon}(x)\cap E\neq \varnothing$.

If $x\in E$ then $x=0,a_1a_2\dots a_n\dots$ where $a_i\in\{4,7\}$. For $\forall \varepsilon>0$ $\exists n\in \mathbb{N}: \varepsilon>10^{-n}$.

If $a_{n+1}=4$ we can take $x_0=0,a_1\dots a_n7a_{n+2}\dots$. We see that $x_0-x=3/10^{n+1}<10^{-n}$. In this case $x_0\in N'_{\varepsilon}(x)\cap E$

If $a_{n+1}=7$ we can take $x_0=0,a_1\dots a_n4a_{n+2}\dots$. We see that $x-x_0=3/10^{n+1}<10^{-n}$. In this case $x_0\in N'_{\varepsilon}(x)\cap E$.

So, $E$ is a perfect set.

Is my proof true?

P.S. Sorry for repeating.

Comment: I find it OK. By the way, isn't this set homeomorphic to Cantor's?

Comment: Dear ajotatxe. Sorry but I don't know what is "homeomorphic"